# Android devices disconnect all the time

Tags: android, linux, disconnect

Since several weeks i have a new Samsung Galaxy s6, and i want to work with it using eclipse/adb/adt/etc. Since the beginning i have many problems to run my app on it. Indeed, when i launch my app on it, sometimes eclipse doesn't find any devices, and sometimes, it disconnects during the launch. I tried many things, like restarting adb, restarting my phone, changing cable, and it's the same.

Then i looked at the /var/log/kern.log file, to see it there was any problems, and indeed i have this :

```
Jul  5 11:02:01 toto-pc kernel: [ 4371.280754] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 34 using xhci_hcd
Jul  5 11:02:01 toto-pc kernel: [ 4371.409883] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6860
Jul  5 11:02:01 toto-pc kernel: [ 4371.409887] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jul  5 11:02:01 toto-pc kernel: [ 4371.409888] usb 3-2: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
Jul  5 11:02:01 toto-pc kernel: [ 4371.409889] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
Jul  5 11:02:01 toto-pc kernel: [ 4371.409891] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 04157df4435d2f26
Jul  5 11:02:01 toto-pc kernel: [ 4371.411108] cdc_acm 3-2:1.1: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
Jul  5 11:02:01 toto-pc kernel: [ 4371.411136] cdc_acm 3-2:1.1: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
Jul  5 11:02:01 toto-pc kernel: [ 4371.936271] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 34
Jul  5 11:02:02 toto-pc kernel: [ 4372.208185] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 35 using xhci_hcd
Jul  5 11:02:02 toto-pc kernel: [ 4372.337309] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6860
Jul  5 11:02:02 toto-pc kernel: [ 4372.337313] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jul  5 11:02:02 toto-pc kernel: [ 4372.337315] usb 3-2: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
Jul  5 11:02:02 toto-pc kernel: [ 4372.337316] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
Jul  5 11:02:02 toto-pc kernel: [ 4372.337318] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 04157df4435d2f26
Jul  5 11:02:02 toto-pc kernel: [ 4372.338470] cdc_acm 3-2:1.1: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
Jul  5 11:02:02 toto-pc kernel: [ 4372.338499] cdc_acm 3-2:1.1: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
Jul  5 11:02:14 toto-pc kernel: [ 4384.069342] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 35
Jul  5 11:02:14 toto-pc kernel: [ 4384.341639] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 36 using xhci_hcd
Jul  5 11:02:14 toto-pc kernel: [ 4384.470804] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6860
Jul  5 11:02:14 toto-pc kernel: [ 4384.470807] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jul  5 11:02:14 toto-pc kernel: [ 4384.470809] usb 3-2: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
Jul  5 11:02:14 toto-pc kernel: [ 4384.470810] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
Jul  5 11:02:14 toto-pc kernel: [ 4384.470812] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 04157df4435d2f26
Jul  5 11:02:14 toto-pc kernel: [ 4384.471853] cdc_acm 3-2:1.1: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
Jul  5 11:02:14 toto-pc kernel: [ 4384.471885] cdc_acm 3-2:1.1: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
Jul  5 11:02:14 toto-pc kernel: [ 4384.872802] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 36
Jul  5 11:02:15 toto-pc kernel: [ 4385.145145] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 37 using xhci_hcd
Jul  5 11:02:30 toto-pc kernel: [ 4400.432980] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 38 using xhci_hcd
Jul  5 11:02:35 toto-pc kernel: [ 4405.558175] usb 3-2: device descriptor read/all, error -110
Jul  5 11:02:35 toto-pc kernel: [ 4405.854003] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 40 using xhci_hcd
Jul  5 11:02:35 toto-pc kernel: [ 4405.966175] usb 3-2: Device not responding to setup address.
Jul  5 11:02:36 toto-pc kernel: [ 4406.169861] usb 3-2: Device not responding to setup address.
Jul  5 11:02:36 toto-pc kernel: [ 4406.373684] usb 3-2: device not accepting address 40, error -71
Jul  5 11:02:36 toto-pc kernel: [ 4406.669518] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 42 using xhci_hcd
Jul  5 11:02:41 toto-pc kernel: [ 4411.794753] usb 3-2: device descriptor read/all, error -110
Jul  5 11:02:42 toto-pc kernel: [ 4412.090692] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 44 using xhci_hcd
Jul  5 11:02:42 toto-pc kernel: [ 4412.202703] usb 3-2: Device not responding to setup address.
Jul  5 11:02:42 toto-pc kernel: [ 4412.406539] usb 3-2: Device not responding to setup address.
Jul  5 11:02:42 toto-pc kernel: [ 4412.610337] usb 3-2: device not accepting address 44, error -71
Jul  5 11:02:42 toto-pc kernel: [ 4412.906258] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 46 using xhci_hcd
Jul  5 11:02:43 toto-pc kernel: [ 4413.035723] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6860
Jul  5 11:02:43 toto-pc kernel: [ 4413.035728] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jul  5 11:02:43 toto-pc kernel: [ 4413.035730] usb 3-2: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
Jul  5 11:02:43 toto-pc kernel: [ 4413.035731] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
Jul  5 11:02:43 toto-pc kernel: [ 4413.035733] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 04157df4435d2f26
Jul  5 11:02:43 toto-pc kernel: [ 4413.037008] cdc_acm 3-2:1.1: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
Jul  5 11:02:43 toto-pc kernel: [ 4413.037047] cdc_acm 3-2:1.1: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
Jul  5 11:02:43 toto-pc kernel: [ 4413.043248] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 46
Jul  5 11:02:43 toto-pc kernel: [ 4413.533866] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 48 using xhci_hcd
Jul  5 11:02:58 toto-pc kernel: [ 4428.821603] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 49 using xhci_hcd
Jul  5 11:02:58 toto-pc kernel: [ 4428.933619] usb 3-2: Device not responding to setup address.
Jul  5 11:02:59 toto-pc kernel: [ 4429.137383] usb 3-2: Device not responding to setup address.
Jul  5 11:02:59 toto-pc kernel: [ 4429.341190] usb 3-2: device not accepting address 49, error -71
```

I get everything of this while i don't touch the phone or the cable.

Thanks in advance.